# VisualSVN Server Change of Authentication - Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, visualsvn-server

We have Windows 2008 windows server in that we are running VisualSVN Server, Presently it has subversion login authentication which will be authenticated locally.

We are planning to go through Windows AD integration, What is the proper way of migration of users? will I loose any data while migration?

I am not much into windows server administration. Can anybody please guide me in this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a "migration" actually.

You will simply have to enable Basic and / or Integrated Windows Authentication in VisualSVN Server Manager and then set authorization settings from a scratch for AD user accounts and groups.